# Factorize matrix expression

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Let $x,y,w,z$ be vectors and $A$ a matrix. Let the dimension agree so that
$$
x^TAy - w^TAz
$$
is well defined.

I am looking for a way to factorize the elements in a form that resemble

$$
k_1^TAk_2,
$$
for some $k_1$ and $k_2$. Is there any way to do that for $x\neq y\neq w\neq z$?

For example, in the case $x = w$ is easily done by

$$
x^\top A(y-z).
$$

What about the general case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $k_1,k_2$ are required to be vectors, then I suspect that there is no such factorization.

On the other hand, we can write

$$
x^TAy - w^TAz = \\
\operatorname{tr}[x^TAy] - \operatorname{tr}[w^TAz] =\\
\operatorname{tr}[Ayx^T] - \operatorname{tr}[Azw^T] =\\
\operatorname{tr}[A(xy^T - wz^T)^T] = \\
\operatorname{vec}(A)^T \cdot \operatorname{vec}(xy^T - wz^T).
$$

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What is the meaning of the parenthesis, how do you stack the vectors in those? Can you refer me to some book or reference that explains that?

Comment: @Apprentice $(x \ \ -w)$ is the matrix whose columns are $x$ and $-w$.

Comment: Is it possible to write it as $(\text{vec}(xy^\top) -\text{vec}(wz^\top))^T\cdot \text{vec}(A)$ @Ben?

Comment: @Apprentice Yes, that works. Also, it turns out that my original answer was incorrect. See my latest edit.

Comment: There should be a transpose on the first term of the last equation I think

Comment: @Apprentice That's right, fixed it